# Как передать в команду в качестве параметра значение контрола?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Хочу, повесить на `TextBox` команду и на нажатие Enter ее вызывать, да так, чтобы в качестве параметра передавался текст.

Самое простое решение- это как-то назвать элемент и сослаться на него:

```
        <TextBox Name="seachTextBox">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding FilterSourceCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=seachTextBox}"/>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
```

А можно как-то хитро сослаться без именования?

Comment: Другой вариант: привязка к свойству Text, а команду привязать к кнопке, у которой будет установлено свойство IsDefault: `<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchPattern}" /><Button Content="Search" Command="{Binding FilterSourceCommand}" IsDefault="True" />` наверняка кнопка у вас уже есть, получится короче. А в команде не использовать параметр, а использовать свойство VM

Comment: @aepot, а чего ответ удалили?